# Converting list of one class to list of another class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am calling a stored procedure from Entity Framework and trying to get result of stored procedure in a model-view class but I am getting error while casting list of Result class I got from entity framework -

Below code I tried, but I am getting error while trying to cast, I tried other way also like `ConvertAll<>` but didn't work -

```
public List<DepartmentModelView> GetDepartmentData()
        {

            using (Model1Container obj = new Model1Container())
            {
                return obj.usp_getDepartment().ToList<usp_getDepartment_Result>().Cast<DepartmentModelView>.ToList();

            }
        }
```

This is the auto generated result class in Model.tt

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    using System;

    public partial class usp_getDepartment_Result
    {
        public Nullable<int> Depid { get; set; }
        public string DepName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I want it to be returned in `DepartmentModelView` class-

```
 public class DepartmentModelView
    {
        public Nullable<int> Depid { get; set; }
        public string DepName { get; set; }
    }
```

Please suggest how could I do this ?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of your Code works, you can use the Linq-Select-Projection:

```
public List<DepartmentModelView> GetDepartmentData()
    {

        using (Model1Container obj = new Model1Container())
        {
            return obj.usp_getDepartment().ToList<usp_getDepartment_Result>().Select(m=>new DepartmentModelView{Depid=m.Depid, DepName=m.DepName}).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement implicit cast in another partial file for `usp_getDepartment_Result`:

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public partial class usp_getDepartment_Result
    {
        static public implicit operator DepartmentModelView(usp_getDepartment_Result input)
        {
            return new DepartmentModelView
            {
                Depid = input.Depid,
                DepName = input.DepName
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then your existing code ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AutoMapper` (from Nuget). You can create a map from one class to another and you can do all kinds of manipulation during the mapping operation for cases where it isn't a straightforward copy of properties like this one.

And for simple cases like this one, Automapper will autowire up the conversion when it finds properties with the same names and types.